# Transformar documento docx a html

Tags: c#, html, .net, conversión-de-tipos, docx

Tengo un documento `docx` ya guardado en `bytes[]` y necesito pasarlo a html para poder mostrarlo en una página.

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio con .NET para desarrollarlo en C#.

Actualmente ya me funciona a partir de pdf que es fácil de transformar a html pero no es el caso de `docx` ni ningún producto de Microsoft ya que no puedo utilizar la librería nativa `interop` ya que no es garantía que el servidor lo tenga instalado.

El resultado final es:

```
strFinalDoc = strFinalDoc.Replace("<body>", "<body>" + documentInfoHtml + "<BR /><BR />");
```

Dónde `documentInfoHtml` es el resultado de transformar los `bytes[]` a html y `strFinalDoc` es simplemente el contenido que reemplaza el `body` de una página.

He encontrado alguna solución pero prácticamente todas utilizan `interop` o bien librerías de pago.

¿Conocéis alguna manera de hacerlo con software libre o proyectos abiertos?

Además tengo que hacer el mismo proceso para ficheros `xls` y `xlsx`.

La respuesta actual es muy buena pero sólo cubre un fichero `doc` y no el `docx`

Es importante también mantener el máximo posible los estilos CSS existentes por lo que respuestas que simplemente extraigan el contenido para generarlo yo en `HTML` no es suficiente en el sentido de que perdería todo el formato.

Comment: ¿Al transformar los bytes en caracteres, obtienes el texto del archivo? Si es así, ¿Por qué no generar tu propio documento HTML?

Comment: Porqué si hago yo la conversión a saco (lo he intentado) sale sólo texto sin ningún tipo de formato.

Comment: pense que ya habias conseguido convertir los docx

Comment: Sí! Pero me gustaría que la respuesta lo tuviera todo! :) sinó el lunes te lo paso para que puedas actualitzar tu respuesta y la acepto. Un saludo!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usando Apache POI es relativamente facil hacerlo. Asi que podemos usar [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) para hacer la trasformación en C#.

Usando como base esta respuesta de [Convert Word to HTML with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901139/3100840)

> Versión para java
>
> ```
> HWPFDocumentCore wordDocument = WordToHtmlUtils.loadDoc(new
> FileInputStream("D:\\temp\\seo\\1.doc"));
>
> WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(
>         DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
>                 .newDocument());
> wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(wordDocument);
> Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
> ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
> DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
> StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);
>
> TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
> Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
> serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
> serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
> serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
> serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
> out.close();
>
> String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
> System.out.println(result);
> ```

Trasformamos esto a C#

```
HWPFDocumentCore wordDocument = WordToHtmlUtils.LoadDoc(@"D:\Hola.doc"); 

WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(
    new XmlDocument());

wordToHtmlConverter.ProcessDocument(wordDocument);

XmlDocument htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.Document;

htmlDocument.Save(@"D:\Hola.html");
```

Te recomiendo que **no bajes** NPOI por nuget (versión actual 2.2.1) y uses la versión 2.1.3.1 pero de la pagina oficial ya que se necesitan dos archivos mas que no vienen en nuget `NPOI.ScratchPad.HSSF.dll` y `NPOI.ScratchPad.HWPF.dll` ambos compilados con NET Framework 2.x y necesita que las otras librerias sean de la version 2.x tambien. Estos 2 archivos los puedes descargar del [Github de NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/tree/master/solution/Lib)

---

Haciendo pruebas parece que la versión de NPOI tiene un bug en el resultado final del HTML, ya que para simular el formato crea el estilo con la primera letra del tipo de etiqueta y un numero incremental

```
<!-- ejemplo POI java-->
span.s1{color:red;}
...
<span class="s1">Hola</span>
```

pero por alguna razón la versión de NET no los genera bien

```
<!-- ejemplo NPOI C#-->
span.s1{color:red;}
...
<span>Hola</span>
```

Quiza tenga que ver con el `Transformer` pero no se cual sera la equivalencia en C#

---

Haciendo un cuenta manual, puede que ya no necesite mas para que se vea bien la salida

```
    ....
    XmlNode node = htmlDocument.FirstChild.LastChild; //encontramos el body
    EditNode(node); //metodo de edición recursiva
    htmlDocument.Save(@"D:\tmp18\Hola.html");
}

Dictionary<string, int> cuenta; //para llevar la cuenta de cada elemento

private void EditNode(XmlNode node) {
    try
    {
        XmlElement xe = (XmlElement)node;     

        xe.SetAttribute("class", cuenta[xe.LocalName].ToString()); //localName seria span o p por ejemplo
        cuenta[xe.LocalName] += 1;
    }
    catch (Exception) { return; }

    if (node.HasChildNodes) {
        foreach (XmlNode x in node.ChildNodes) {                
            EditNode(x);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola @jasilva, Tu respuesta me parece muy buena, estoy intentando aplicarlo pero me salta un error: `The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)` estoy bsucando el qué a ver..

Comment: Ese error es porque usas un archivo `docx` y esta parte usa solo los archivos `doc` deja actualizo la respuesta

Comment: Ya he descubierto cómo hacerlo investigando más con el NPO (y también lo he echo con XLS y XLSX.) Puedes actualizar tu respuesta con el docx? Así lo dejamos cerrado :)

Answer (score 4):

Pues un documento de Word esta compuesto por XML, entonces porque no partiendo desde este punto solo conviertes tu `XML` a `HTML`. 
Mira en la página de [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx#Anchor_6) te muestran la estructura que tiene un documento word en xml, aquí te dejo la estructura:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
  <CoreProperties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/package/2005/06/md/core-properties"> 
   <Title>Word Document Sample</Title> 
   <Subject>Microsoft Office Word 2007</Subject> 
   <Creator>2007 Microsoft Office System User</Creator> 
   <Keywords/> 
   <Description>2007 Microsoft Office system .docx file</Description> 
   <LastModifiedBy>2007 Microsoft Office System User</LastModifiedBy> 
   <Revision>2</Revision> 
   <DateCreated>2005-05-05T20:01:00Z</DateCreated> 
   <DateModified>2005-05-05T20:02:00Z</DateModified> 
  </CoreProperties>
```

Y de igual forma en la [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx#Anchor_6) también te dan un ejemplo del uso del `XmlDocument Class`, he aquí un ejemplo de ello:

```
 using System;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Xml;

 public class Sample
 {
   public static void Main()
   {
     //Create the XmlDocument.
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.LoadXml("<?xml version='1.0' ?>" +
            "<book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
            "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
            "</book>");

     //Display the document element.
     Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml);
  }
 }
```

Ahora, para accesar a los nodos  lo puedes hacer así:

```
  public XmlNode GetBook(string uniqueAttribute, XmlDocument doc)
  {
      XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
      nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "http://www.contoso.com/books");
      string xPathString = "//bk:books/bk:book[@ISBN='" + uniqueAttribute +      "']";
      XmlNode xmlNode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xPathString, nsmgr);
     return xmlNode;
  }
```

Entonces ahí es donde ya le concatenas todo tu código `HTML`. Los códigos los vi en la [MSDN XmlDocument Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

## Conversión

Como ya te has dado cuenta el docx no es otra cosa que un xml zipeado, y por lo tanto fácilmente convertible a HTML.

## Envío al cliente

Para enviar la información al cliente (para asegurarte de que no vea solo un txt) hay que acordarse de enviar antes los Headers:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf8
Content-Length: 12345
```

En charset hay que poner lo que corresponda y en content length también (en bytes, no en chars, recordemos que un char utf8 puede medir más de un byte). El length sirve para que el navegador sepa cuántos bytes espera y pueda poner la barrita de progreso cuando el documento es largo.

## Compactar

Una vez que funcione sin compactar podrías evaluar usar un middleware o un módulo para enviar la información compactada (gzip por ejemplo)